# How to pre-populate Facebook Comment box other social comment box using a javascript button

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-comments, buttonclick

I have designed a text decorator for use on social networks. Since the text is generated to a text box and should be shared on social sites, I need to enable mobile phone users to copy-paste the decorated text into a social comment box by just clicking one button.

The challenge is that the fb comment box, or disqus and others are offered in iframes. 
Can someone figure out the correction for my button code?

```
input value="Encool" type="button" class="button" style="width:70%" 
       onclick="window.frames['iframename'].document.getElementById('formname').textareaname.value=    document.getElementById('decoratedtextarea').value;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't so that. An Iframe served by another domain is inaccessible due to the **Same Origin Policy**. This is to prevent forms of cross-site-scripting attacks. (which are not dissimilar to what you want to do)

Comment: HI Diodeus. I understand about XSS but in this case i am looking for a revolutionary solution for mobile phone users to easily share text online. This, by the way is could end up to be handy for a lot more other functions online. Could you to suggest me another generic social comment box that does not come in an iframe or a way to create one or enable the function. You can check my site here: http://fbcooler.tumblr.com/

Comment: If you could automate posting this way it would lead to abuse, which is why browsers have been engineered to prevent this. Also, social sites generally strip out HTML tags in postings, so "decorated text" will become plain text. I think your only choice is to write your own non-browser-based application,

Comment: Ok Deodius for one, my text works fine after being posted through on most browsers. I am just trying to populate a textbox then letting the end user choose whether to post or not. Its only because mobile phone browsers cannot copy-paste. Even if the user has to go through a second page to validate their post...

Comment: oh by the way, here is one perfect example for twitter http://goo.gl/ILgGo. It works via share link querystring. How could i achieve the same thing for fb at http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php for linkedin?

Comment: Technically this is not entirely true as it's up to the operator of the remote site whether they provide a way of doing this (some do, some don't), SOP is just used to prevent it without permission. AFAIK Facebook and Disqus don't provide a way to do it however.